# Failed to deploy war on heroku

Tags: scala, maven, heroku, maven-3

**trying to deploy war to heroku**
using maven 3.2.5

```
mvn clean heroku:deploy-war
```

**getting this exception:**

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.heroku.sdk:heroku-maven-plugin:0.3.0:deploy-war (default-cli) on project MyApp: Failed to deploy application: There was an exception invoking the remote service: HTTP(404): https://api.heroku.com/apps/MyApp/config-vars -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal com.heroku.sdk:heroku-maven-plugin:0.3.0:deploy-war (default-cli) on project MyApp: Failed to deploy application
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:120)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:355)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:216)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:160)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException: Failed to deploy application
    at com.heroku.sdk.maven.DeployWarMojo.execute(DeployWarMojo.java:58)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:132)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: com.heroku.sdk.deploy.Curl$CurlException: There was an exception invoking the remote service: HTTP(404)
    at com.heroku.sdk.deploy.Curl.handleResponse(Curl.java:94)
    at com.heroku.sdk.deploy.Curl.get(Curl.java:22)
    at com.heroku.sdk.deploy.App.getConfigVars(App.java:139)
    at com.heroku.sdk.deploy.App.deploy(App.java:77)
    at com.heroku.sdk.deploy.App.deploy(App.java:93)
    at com.heroku.sdk.deploy.WarApp.deploy(WarApp.java:38)
    at com.heroku.sdk.maven.DeployWarMojo.execute(DeployWarMojo.java:54)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://api.heroku.com/apps/MyApp/config-vars
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1624)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
    at com.heroku.sdk.deploy.Curl.handleResponse(Curl.java:90)
    ... 27 more
```

**this is how my pom looks like:**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.avi</groupId>
    <artifactId>MyApp</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <description>My GoTickets Web App</description>
    <inceptionYear>2014</inceptionYear>
    <properties>
        <scala.version>2.11.4</scala.version>
        <spray.version>1.3.1</spray.version>
        <akka.version>2.3.8</akka.version>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>scala-tools.org</id>
            <name>Scala-Tools Maven2 Repository</name>
            <url>http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>scala-tools.org</id>
            <name>Scala-Tools Maven2 Repository</name>
            <url>http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases</url>
        </pluginRepository>

    </pluginRepositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
            <version>${scala.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.9</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <groupId>org.specs2</groupId>
            <artifactId>specs2-core_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.15</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <groupId>com.typesafe.akka</groupId>
            <artifactId>akka-testkit_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>${akka.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
            <artifactId>scalatest_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.spray</groupId>
            <artifactId>spray-can</artifactId>
            <version>${spray.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.spray</groupId>
            <artifactId>spray-routing</artifactId>
            <version>${spray.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.spray</groupId>
            <artifactId>spray-json_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>${spray.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.typesafe.akka</groupId>
            <artifactId>akka-actor_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>${akka.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.typesafe.akka</groupId>
            <artifactId>akka-slf4j_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>${akka.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/scala</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>src/test/scala</testSourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <scalaVersion>${scala.version}</scalaVersion>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.heroku.sdk</groupId>
                <artifactId>heroku-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <appName>MyApp</appName>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: You're getting a file not found from `https://api.heroku.com/apps/MyApp/config-vars`. Have you created this app using `heroku create -n`?

Comment: @SeanKuhlman yes , I create the app using heroku create -n . also mvn clean install pass successfully

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `appName` is incorrect in the Heroku `plugin` configuration. Heroku apps must start with a letter and can only contain lowercase letters, numbers, and dashes. Therefore `MyApp` cannot be correct.

Check your apps page in the Heroku dashboard and find the name of your application then update the configuration accordingly. Here is an example of the plugin config with a randomly named Heroku app:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.heroku.sdk</groupId>
    <artifactId>heroku-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.3.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <appName>hidden-badlands-1234</appName>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```